# Two factor authentication over MS Authenticator

Tags: azure, multi-factor-authentication, authenticator

Im the only administrator on Azure platform for my organisation, im using two factor authentication over MS Authenticator APP to approve loging, actually i have a problem, i lost my phone and can't approve login over MS Authenticator APP, Any help will be appreciated, many thanks, Get new connexion in my new MS Authenticator APP to approve my connexion to Azure

Reset Two factor authentication

Comment: This question is not related to programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

If you have lost your phone and are unable to approve login over the Microsoft Authenticator app, you will need another cloud services admin to reset your Multi-Factor Authentication settings. The admin can follow the steps outlined in the "Resolution" section of the following Microsoft article:  [Can't use Azure Multi-Factor Authentication to sign in to cloud services after you lose your phone or the phone number changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/cannot-use-mfa-signin-lose-phone#cant-use-azure-multi-factor-authentication-to-sign-in-to-cloud-services-after-you-lose-your-phone-or-the-phone-number-changes).

Steps:

Ask another cloud services admin to reset your Multi-Factor Authentication settings. To do this, the admin should follow these steps:

1. Sign in to the cloud service portal as an admin.
2. Go to  https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/usermanagement/multifactorverification.aspx.
   [image]
3. Select the check box for the admin account whose Multi-Factor Authentication settings you want to reset.
   [image]
4. Select  **Manage user settings**.
5. Select the  **Require selected users to provide contact methods again**  check box, and then select  **Save**.
   [image]
   References:

- [Can't use Azure Multi-Factor Authentication to sign in to cloud services after you lose your phone or the phone number changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/cannot-use-mfa-signin-lose-phone#cant-use-azure-multi-factor-authentication-to-sign-in-to-cloud-services-after-you-lose-your-phone-or-the-phone-number-changes)